# Setting innodb_log_file_size crashes MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, logfile

So, I'd like to be able to set the max log file size to 64M, but after doing so with `innodb_log_file_size=64M` MySQL starts OK, but nothing seems to work properly.

**EDIT:** and by properly I mean not at all. Setting other InnoDB variables aren't causing any problems.

How should I go about troubleshooting this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure MySQL shuts down cleanly, and delete (or move elsewhere) all `ib_logfile*` files from MySQL data directory (`/var/lib/mysql/` usually).

I've tested it and worked for me. Here's [source of this hint](http://mysqldatabaseadministration.blogspot.com/2007/04/innodb-performance-optimization.html).

InnoDB reports some errors in `show table status` comment field. You'll find other problems in MySQL error log (`hostname.err` in MySQL data directory).

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem too, and as per @porneL's answer, here were my specific bash steps to correct this:

```
service mysql stop              # Stop MySQL
rm /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0   # Delete log file 1
rm /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1   # Delete log file 2
vim my.conf                     # Change innodb_log_file_size = 64M
service mysql start             # Start MySQL
```

I found these specific steps on the [MySQL forums](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,298678,298782#msg-298782).

Answer (score 1):

Before changing the [**innodb_log_file_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size), you must flush all remaining transactional data out of it. You simply set [**innodb_fast_shutdown**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_fast_shutdown) to 0 or 2.

- innodb_fast_shutdown = 0 : InnoDB does a slow shutdown, a full purge and an insert buffer merge before shutting down
- innodb_fast_shutdown = 2 : InnoDB flushes its logs and shuts down cold, as if MySQL had crashed; no committed transactions are lost, but the crash recovery operation makes the next startup take longer.

In light of this, this is how you handle it

```
mysql -ANe"SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 2"
vi /etc/my.cnf                  # Change innodb_log_file_size = 64M
service mysql stop              # Stop MySQL
rm /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0   # Delete log file 1
rm /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1   # Delete log file 2
service mysql start             # Start MySQL
```